# Embedding an image in web server with Clack/ningle

Tags: http, webserver, common-lisp, binary-data

I am working on a small web server in Common Lisp and I am having trouble including binary data like png's. To read static files like a png, I have created a macro that will add a new Ningle route based on what kind of file specified by the user. This includes a reader-function argument which will create data from a filename. It works fine with text-based files like css, html, js (text/css, text/html, text/js, etc.).

How do I make Ningle read binary data as content?

Here is my code

```
(defun read-file (&key (filename "index.html"))
  (let
      ((in (open filename :if-does-not-exist nil))
       (out ""))
    (when in
      (loop for line = (read-line in nil)
            while line do
              (progn
                (setf out (concatenate 'string out (format nil "~a~%" line)))))
      (close in)
      out)))

(defun make-adjustable-string (s)
               (make-array (length s)
                           :fill-pointer (length s)
                           :adjustable t
                           :initial-contents s
                           :element-type (array-element-type s)))

(defun read-binary (&key (filename "img/free.png"))
  (let
      ((in (open filename :if-does-not-exist nil :external-format :unix :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)))
       (out ""))
    (when in
      (loop for byte = (read-byte in nil)
            while byte do
              (progn
                (setf out (make-adjustable-string out))
                (vector-push-extend (code-char byte) out)))
      (close in)
      out)))

(defmacro add-static-file-handler (filetype &key (html-type (concatenate 'string "text/" filetype)) (reader-function #'read-file))
  (setf (ningle:route *app* (concatenate 'string "*/:file." filetype))
        #'(lambda (params)
            (let*
                ((path (car (cdr (assoc :splat params))))
                 (filename (concatenate 'string path "/" (cdr (assoc :file params)) (concatenate 'string "." filetype)))
                 (file (funcall reader-function :filename (concatenate 'string "." filename))))
              (cond
                (file (list 200 (list :content-type html-type) (list file)))
                (t (list 404 '(:content-type "text/html") (list (concatenate 'string filename " could not be found")))))))))
                                     
(add-static-file-handler "css")
(add-static-file-handler "html")
(add-static-file-handler "js")
(add-static-file-handler "txt" :html-type "text/plain" )

(add-static-file-handler "png" :html-type "image/png" :reader-function read-binary)
```

First of all this is really slow. There must be a faster method.
Secondly, as an example when I throw a 10x10 png at it it comes up with:

```
PNG

IHDR

2Ï½dêIDAT]1KÃpÄWP·BAppt.D\\ÅUprÜ³º8º%ÃÐÉID5! ADdÃ?­©Ç»w¼{$¼·+»\\·
                                                                 ÙåÓ45°èA$ÉowvNù»:Ë2×uÇ±={
                                                                                          ×zbç²
ëÁÉ¡(¦i8»:9t\\ÈI¸^%y{$ß\\Ë±Y<û2ÝX÷!É0ØG3Ú'?óðÖ çaV3Âí=ìIü©»â[IEND®B`
```

which seems kinda right. I mean it looks like a binary file. However, when viewed on the browser it's just the default broken image icon.

Comment: `add-static-file-handler` should almost certainly not be a macro.  It's current definition is also not legal since its expansion is a function and functions are not externalizable objects.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way whould be to give Ningle a chance to process everything. Just return a pathname from the handler:

```
CL-USER> (defvar *app* (make-instance 'ningle:app))
*APP*

CL-USER> (setf (ningle:route *app* "/some.png")
               #P"/Users/art/Downloads/demo.png")
#P"/Users/art/Downloads/demo.png"

CL-USER> (clack:clackup *app*)
Hunchentoot server is started.
Listening on 127.0.0.1:5000.
#S(CLACK.HANDLER::HANDLER
   :SERVER :HUNCHENTOOT
   :ACCEPTOR #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "clack-handler-hunchentoot" RUNNING
                {1017FC2433}>)
```

And Ningle will do the rest:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:5000/some.png
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET /some.png HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 06 May 2021 20:35:59 GMT
< Server: Hunchentoot 1.3.0
< Content-Length: 50661
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Last-Modified: Mon, 19 Apr 2021 08:53:21 GMT
< Content-Type: image/png
<
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you try to mix character and binary data. When you call `(make-adjustable-string "")` a new string is created, while what you actually need is:

```
(make-array 0
            :fill-pointer t
            :adjustable t
            :element-type 'unsigned-byte)
```

Next, speaking about performance, indeed, reading a file one byte at a time is a synonym of inefficiency. You want to utilize `read-sequence`. Besides, it might be a good idea to not read the whole sequence into memory (sine files may be pretty large) and instead stream the contents in chunks (say of size 8k).

Overall, approaching such a problem (which is not at all novel), I'd first take a look at some existing code. For example, you can draw inspiration from how Hunchentoot operates on files in its [HANDLE-STATIC-FILE](https://github.com/edicl/hunchentoot/blob/0023dd3927e5840f1f02f9a8bdab2b4a7037c652/misc.lisp#L151) function.